# Deploy JAVA web project into live server(AWS) using WAR file

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, maven-3

I got an error when deploy the JAVA web application into live server. i have used maven tool for version control.Also uploaded the application into live server and when i use the "mvn deploy" command to deploy, i am getting an error.
Error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project PROJECT_NAME: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access scp:///var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/PROJECT_NAME with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access scp:///var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/PROJECT_NAME using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory: java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Also i have added the distributionManagement inside the pom.xml

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        <id>corp1</id>
        <name>Corporate Repository</name>
        <url>scp:///var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/PROJECT_NAME</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maven `deploy` goal is not intended to be used for deploying artifacts to application servers. It is intended to be used for deploying artifacts and their associated metadata (such as the pom.xml file) to a repository manager such as [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype) or [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/).

Consider using the [Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/) for this purpose instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an application in AWS Elastic beanstalk and host your WAR file and manage your application

Steps

1. Export your java application as WAR file.
2. Create an application inside Elastic beanstalk in AWS server.
3. Upload your WAR file, It will give you link to run your web application.

Reference Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umQxKX78EsU